# What would be the first use of the noun 'longboarding' for skateboarding, surfing or skiing?

Tags: etymology

The skateboard *longboard* goes back to Hawaii in the 50s, surfing back much earlier, and skiing back into the nineteenth century yet I can't find incidences in print earlier than the 70s. Many historical accounts are published more recently but have no citation to track down.

Here is one such example from [a skiing magazine](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_KK6VKM0njdwC/page/n27):

> The earliest longboard racing began in January 1861 in the  town of Onion Valley, but within a month longboarding had spread 30 miles north to history's second-oldest recorded race site in Eureka Bowl. Though longboarding faded as the mines closed, the spectacle left an undying California dream of resuscitating this glorious heritage. And the Plumas Ski Club has succeeded in doing just that — not an easy thing.
>
> To fulfill the dream, the Plumas Ski Club was founded in the early 1950s by skiers from the Quincy-Portola section of Plumas County who first raised a regular rope-tow ski area in the Eureka Bowl near Johnstown, knowing that it was a historic longboard site. As a modern rope-tow area, Eureka Bowl went through the usual small-ski-area-life-and-death struggle while elsewhere in California one-shot longboard revival races intermittently popped up. During a typical longboard event in 1964, longboarder Jerry Burelle proved that longboarding was not just a matter of standing on skis in a sort of toboggan ride — Burelle took on 1964 Olympic medalist Billy Kidd (on modern downhill skis) and beat Kidd to the bottom. No immediate follow-up races were held — but the longboard would just not die.

I have trawled the usual newspaper archives without success.

Comment: Here you go: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=longboard%2C+longboarding&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clongboard%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clongboarding%3B%2Cc0  You'll need to dig through the uses linked at the bottom and see which ones are "real" and which are some sort of artifact.

Comment: Thank you. I did give this a go, but you would be surprised how many times it turns out to be a false positive for either 'long board' or 'long beard' or alternatives. All of them, as it turns out. Good suggestion, though, for which much thanks.

Comment: (Discounting shuffleboard, it looks like 1968 is the first use.)

Comment: Where do you see the 1968 use? By default my search tools reflect my UK location so some things don't always appear without addressing this.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=PBrwAAAAMAAJ&q=%22longboard%22&dq=%22longboard%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQgf6jz4vMAhWEJh4KHc09Cn0Q6AEILDAD

Comment: Thank you, but while that work has 'longboard riding' is does not have 'longboarding' drat it. Thank you nonetheless for your kind (and instant) help.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see "longboarding" until later.

Comment: The term crops up in windsurfing as well, although that is almost certain not to be the earliest use.

Answer (score 1):

The Oxford English Dictionary can shed some light on this. The earliest attestation is 1950 for the ski sense:

> Although she readily admits she is still a novice, she should handle her longboards with considerable dexterity if she improves as rapidly in skiing as she did in bowling.
>   <sub>Daily Inter Lake: Dec 24, 1950</sub>

And 1970 for the surfboard sense:

> At left is Dennis Heussner, captain of the Australian surf team and national longboard champion.
>   <sub>[Santa Cruz Sentinel: April 2, 1970](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/?a=d&d=SCS19700402.1.3&e=-------en--20--1--txt-txIN--------1)</sub>

The OED explains why it may have taken so long to see *longboard* used in the surfing sense:

> The surfboards so named were originally the ordinary kind and hence may only have received this designation after the appearance of the shortboard. In the following quotations *long* and *short* are probably simply ad hoc descriptions of especially long and short surfboards:
>
> > Duke Kahanamoku built his great 16-foot hollow redwood board along about the same time [1910]... Duke did some of the most beautiful riding I have ever seen on his new long board.
>
> > About 1903 we used a short board a few feet long, rather thin and wide, like a wash board.

Both of those quotes are attributed to a 1935 publication called *Hawaiian Surfboard*.

(It's also worth mentioning that there are some hits for *longboard* that date back to the 1800s, but those refer to especially long moldboards, used in certain tractors.)